# Does this method have any other name according to Numerical Analysis?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

See the book [OPTIMIZATION: Algorithms and Applications](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Optimization_%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications%20%5BArora%202015-05-21%5D.pdf) by Rajesh Kumar Arora, Page-$44$.

> **2.3.4   Cubic Polynomial Fit**
>
> In this method, the function f(x) to be minimized is approximated by a cubic  polynomial $P(x)$ as
>
> $$P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3  \qquad  (2.7)$$
>
> If the function $f(x)$ is evaluated at four
>   different points, then the polynomial  coefficients $a0$, $a1$, $a2$, and $a4$
>   can be evaluated by solving four simultaneous linear equations.
>   Alternatively, if the value of the function and its derivatives  are
>   available at two points, the polynomial coefficients can still be
>   evaluated.  Once a polynomial is approximated for the function, the
>   minimum point can  be evaluated using the polynomial coefficients.
>
> The first step in this search method is to bracket the minimum of the
>   func- tion between two points, x1 and x2, such that the following
>   conditions hold:
>
> $$ f′(x1)f′(x2) < 0  \qquad (2.8) $$
>
> Using the information of
>   $f(x_1), f′(x_1), f(x_2)$, and $f′(x_2)$, the minimum point of  the
>   approximating cubic polynomial can be given as
>
> [image]

I am trying to learn this algorithm. I am searching this algorithm on the Internet but isn't finding anything. I have a feeling that this algorithm probably has other name(s).

Does this method/algorithm have any other name according to Numerical Analysis?

Comment: Readers may feel you've cut corners by posting mainly a link and an image.  I'm sure your own description of an algorithm would be more compelling to read.  Youve been around awhile, so presumably you know about MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  If not, I'd be happy to point you to more information.

Comment: Are you asking about the cubic interpolation forms? Or about a method to bracket a minimum? Or about a method to find the polynomial minimum based on a bracket?

Comment: @IlikeSerena, actually, I don't know. Coz, I don't have any idea about the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *cubic interpolation* will work?

Comment: I googled for "cubic interpolation optimization" and found this relevant video: https://youtu.be/W-Rcs26oFMM